# Unable to replace parameter values in batch file - PostBuildScript plugin Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) plugin in Jenkins to trigger some windows batch command in post build action

I add Execute Script in Post build action in the Job

[image]

And this is what i have written in `directory.bat` to create a directory with current time + environment + job name

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a

set time=%TIME:~0,2%"_"%TIME:~3,2%

mkdir D:\Report_Backup\%date:/=%"_"%time%"_"%Environment%"_"%JOB_NAME%\%test-results

xcopy "D:\bvt_workspace\project-name\test-results" D:\Report_Backup\%date:/=%"_"%time%"_"%Environment%"_"%JOB_NAME%\test-results /E /S /Q /Y
```

Unfortunately, `Environment` and `JOB_NAME` didn't get replace. But if i replace same code in `Execute Windows Batch Command` in Build Step, It works like a charm.

[image]

**Note:** I can't add multiple `Build Step` as I'm using one to trigger the build.

Any idea, How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the [Script executed by PostiBuildScript plugin is unable to use Environment variable defined in Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11790) issue.

The suggested workaround is to configure your plugin to pass the desired environment variables as arguments to the batch script, in your case:

```
D:\directory.bat $Environment $JOB_NAME
```

And at the beginning of your `directory.bat`:

```
set Environment=%1
set JOB_NAME=%2
...
```